# What does this piece of CSS fix do in an iE7.css file?

Tags: css

```
#sidebar ul li a { height:1%; zoom:1; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ensures the `<a>` tag [`hasLayout`](http://haslayout.net/haslayout).

Comment: What do you mean by hasLayout? And whats that got to do with the price of fish?

Comment: @Solidariti - hasLayout is an Internet Explorer concept related to the way it renders elements.  It's often necessary to give an element layout to resolve IE CSS bugs.